# select2 disable / enabled not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a select element with select2 plugin. Version is 4.0. It works well but i cant change disabled option dynamically.

```
$('#list1').select2({
    theme: "bootstrap",
    disabled: true,
    placeholder: "Parsel",
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    allowClear: true,
    closeOnSelect: true,
});
```

As you can see, disabled is true. I cant change disabled option dynamically. It work well if i delete disabled option.

Im using this code for try to change option;

```
$("#list1").select2({ disabled : false });
```

or

```
$("#list1").select2('enable');
```

How can i change select element's disabled option ?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Basic jQuery seems to solve this problem quite nice:

Enable:

```
$("#list1").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Disable:

```
$("#list1").attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: Actually, this not fix my problem. But after i change my html codes, it works well. Thanks.

Comment: @AtakanSavaş,  if you put your answer, we all would profit.

Comment: @AtakanSavaş what did you change, don't leave us hanging

Comment: @TimBogdanov I dont remember at all but try to disable parent item.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use `prop` instead of `attr` in jQuery.
Use `true or false` to set the `disabled status`.

eg:

```
Enable dropdown - $("#list1").prop('disabled', false);
Disable dropdown - $("#list1").prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: It's not just better; that's the correct and only guaranteed way to do it using jQuery.

Comment: Also note the official example for [disabling a select2 control](https://select2.org/appearance#disabling-a-select2-control).

Answer (score 0):

Try this for what you need

```
$('#list1').select2("enable",true)
```

Comment: gives an error. says : .select2(...).enable is not a function

Comment: ok i tried it too. this time it not give any error but nothing changed. i think there is different problem but i cant find yet.

Comment: i think you should start your dropdown disabled directly in html `<select disabled></select>` not via javascript

Comment: i cant change any another option. but i cant find why.